# Can a meteor shower have a period of less than 1 year?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, comet

This question is inspired by the SE question [Can a meteor shower have a interval greater than 1 year?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60400/can-a-meteor-shower-have-a-interval-greater-than-1-year)

Most meteor showers repeat yearly (or natural multiples of 1 year).  Can a meteor shower have a period of less than 1 year?

Confession: this question is more appropriate for SE Astronomy, but since it is an extension of an established SE question, I thought I may be welcome on SE. It is a thinly veiled excuse to post a link to the NASA video simulation in the answer below. The link is a Christmas present to all the SE members who appreciate the beautiful dance of orbital mechanics.

Comment: As they are defined now, no.  While it is possible for a single parent body to cause more than one shower (as noted on Woody's answer), they would be named based on their apparent radiant point.  And the radiant is the determined based on the sum of the Earth's velocity and the particle's velocity.

Comment: @GregMiller ... good point. But by that definition, two debris orbits which happened to have parallel relative velocity vectors where each intersected Earth’s orbit would be considered to be “the same” shower.

Comment: I won't disagree there's ambiguity in the current system.  If you look at the IAU's list of established showers, you'll see the first ones are named after entire constellations, the later ones are named after stars within constellations, and after that, a month, then the star name.  I'm pretty sure the convention of naming them based on their radiant pre dates any understanding of what caused them. https://www.ta3.sk/IAUC22DB/MDC2022/Roje/roje_lista.php?corobic_roje=0&sort_roje=0

Answer (score 20):

**Answer: Yes**, but only if the debris orbit’s Latus Rectum is in the plane of the ecliptic **and** the Semi Latus Rectum is 1AU. Meteor showers will be 6 months apart, but have different radiant points so it may not initially be obvious to observers the two showers are linked.

This is most easily demonstrated in the special case where the debris orbit is coplanar with the ecliptic:

[image]

Edit: Any debris orbit coplanar with the ecliptic which has one vertex within 1 AU of the sun will cut the Earth's orbit in 2 places.

However, it also applies in the more general case where the debris orbit is inclined to the ecliptic around the Latus Rectum axis, but not inclined around the Major Axis.

[image]

With all the orbital variables possible, the chance is small that a comet’s orbit semi latus rectum intersects the Earth’s orbit. As a result, most showers are annual. It begs the question of how many comet debris orbits are there in the solar system which never intersect the Earth’s orbit. We would be unaware of them.

This NASA interactive video https://www.meteorshowers.org/view/iau-4  is a spectacular simulation of the orbital mechanics of a meteor shower. Click through the menu choices and select <Geminids – mid December>. Set speed to slow.

[image]

In the example Geminid orbit, the comet debris orbit inclination produces only one intersection. Thus, there is one meteor shower a year, when the Earth crosses the path of the comet debris.

Comment: Thanks for the interactive video link! Well worth watching!

Comment: This really depends on how you define "meteor shower".  I'd call your example two showers, because they've got different radiants.

Comment: Oh! At first I was confused why the criteria is so complicated - many more elliptical orbits will intersect in two places, but when not 180° apart, it's not really *periodic* at 6 months - it's two showers every year. *Nice!*